# Calculating Total salary, Based on Hours in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to write a `query` to to calculate total pay base on working hours.

In my case I have two tables :

1. `machineTypes` with fields `machine_rent`(per hour bases).
2. `machines` (it maintains all the information of machine that comes on daily basis like: `machine_name`, `timein`, `timeout`, `task`)

Now I want to populate the total amount of particular machine, that how many hours that machine worked and then multiply  with the `machine_rent` as to calculate the `totalpay`.

Comment: lets say same machine daily comes for particular time, now I have to sum up the total time (that will be subtraction of time in and time out) then multiply by machine rent to populate total amount whaterver hours that machine worked. i want only the formula to get accurate calculations.

Comment: Try adding some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and linking back to it in a comment here. Then we have something to play with and don't have to waste our time making up dummy data to test queries. You've pretty much described what you need to do - `sum()` the `interval` created by subtracting the `out` time from the `in` time, then multiply that sum by the `machine_rent` obtained by joining `machines` against `machineTypes` on the primary->foreign key link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, how about [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1d280/3)?

I created some random usage and took the current on-demand AWS per-instance cost (Linux in Virginia).

Exercise for the reader: now computing the grand total should be self-evident.